# Order a queryset by a field in another queryset

Tags: django, sorting, django-queryset

In my django blog app, I have a model for Bookmark, which includes fields pointing to Post and User, and a field for when the bookmark was created.

```py
# models

class Post(models.Model):
    # ...

    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    body = RichTextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    # ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']


class Bookmark(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=CASCADE,
        related_name="bookmarked_post"
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=CASCADE,
        related_name="bookmarks"
    )
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']
```

I have a view to display my users' bookmarks. I want to order the posts queryset in the order they were bookmarked, with the recently bookmarked posts first.

```py
# views.py

@login_required
def bookmarks_view(request):

    bookmarks = Bookmark.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    bookmarked_posts = Post.objects.filter(
        bookmarked_post__in=bookmarks).order_by(???)

    return render(request, 'bookmarks.html', {'posts': bookmarked_posts})
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to order my Posts queryset by the created_on field in the Bookmark model. To add additional complexity, both the Post and Bookmark model have a created_on field.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? I've scoured the django documentation and SO and not finding what I need, possibly I just don't know the right keywords... Or have I set up my models incorrectly to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```py
bookmarks = Bookmark.objects.filter(user=u0)
bookmarked_posts = Post.objects.filter(
    bookmarked_post__in=bookmarks
).order_by("-bookmarked_post__created_on")
```

You can drop the `__created_on` at the end - Django will then use the default `ordering` specified on the related model. The `-` at the beginning means descending, so newer dates come first.

See also [the documentation for order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by):

> To order by a field in a different model, use the same syntax as when you are querying across model relations. That is, the name of the field, followed by a double underscore (`__`), followed by the name of the field in the new model, and so on for as many models as you want to join.

Because you specified the related name as `bookmarked_post`, that's also the name of the field you need to specify, from the perspective of `Post`, just like you used it in the `filter`.

Without the `related_name`, it would look like this:

```py
bookmarks = Bookmark.objects.filter(user=u0)
bookmarked_posts = Post.objects.filter(
    bookmark__in=bookmarks
).order_by("-bookmark__created_on")
```

(Note that you may want to specify [a `unique_together` constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for `post` and `user` on the `Bookmark` model, to make sure that a post can only be bookmarked once per user)